# Command button enable/disable based on textbox value

Tags: date, ms-access, vba

I am trying to enable/disable a command button based on the value of a textbox. Ex. "08-09-2015 15:06:24", taken from a table column field

It seems that it will either enable OR disable it, depending on < or >.

I want it to find out if txt.Value is MORE than 15 hours ago, then it should activate the button. If not, leave it "false"

The textbox and command button are on the same form.

This is what I have so far, and apparently not working.

```vb
Public Sub Kommandoknap184_Click()
If Me.txtOpdTid.Value < DateAdd("h", -15, Date) Then
Kommandoknap35.Enabled = False
Else
Kommandoknap35.Enabled = True
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: try "me!Kommandoknap35.Enabled" not "Kommandoknap35.Enabled", however I usually use the visible property for something like this. If they can't use the button, don't even make it visible.  "me.visible = False"

Comment: sorry that should be "me.kommandoknap35.visible = false"

Comment: As I ponder this question, it might be better to disable or hide your button in the prior to clicking on it, or instead of disabling the button, run your check, if it doesn't meet the criteria, use a msgBox to tell the user it's not valid data, if it does, then run your code.  I don't know that making a button disabled on the click event of the same button is the most logical approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Date()` gives you the current date with midnight as the time.  `Now()` gives you the current date and time.  So I think you want `Now()` instead of `Date()`.

```vb
Public Sub Kommandoknap184_Click()
If Me.txtOpdTid.Value < DateAdd("h", -15, Now) Then
    ' Value is MORE than 15 hours ago, then it should activate the button
    Me.Kommandoknap35.Enabled = True
Else
    Me.Kommandoknap35.Enabled = False
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It's working, so now gotta put it as Auto_Open() sub :D

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there are two problems with your code.

1. In the *DateAdd* function you want to use *Now()* instead of *Date()*. *Now()* will include the current time along with the date. This is important since you are comparing the number of hours and not the number of days.
2. The enable/disable logic is backwards (enabling the button when it should be disabled and vice-versa).

Below is a simplified version with the corrections:

```
Public Sub Kommandoknap184_Click()
    Dim isMoreThan15HoursAgo As Boolean
    isMoreThan15HoursAgo = Me.txtOpdTid < DateAdd("h", -15, Now)
    Me.Kommandoknap35.Enabled = isMoreThan15HoursAgo
End Sub
```

You might also consider having this code run in the *After Update* event of the text box instead of when clicking a separate button. This would make the enable/disable of the button more seamless.